# C++ iterating over a vector in a callback

Tags: c++

I'm writing a unit test where I need to call the function "setMaterial"(see below) every time the user presses the '1' key:

```
auto buttonPress = [this] {
    for (int i = 0; i <= mMaterials.size(); i++)
    {
        mAcoustics->setMaterial(mMaterials[i]);
    }
};

InputManager::bindKeyFunction(0x31 /* '1' key */, buttonPress, ETriggerEvent::OnRelease);
```

"mMaterials" is a `std::vector` that holds all my materials.

Now this is the result I'm trying to get:

User presses '1':
`mAcoustics->setMaterial(mMaterials[1]);`

User presses '1' again: 
`mAcoustics->setMaterial(mMaterials[2]);`

and when it reaches the last element of my vector, it should loop back to the first one and start again.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: `int i = 0; for (;;) { if (i == mMaterials.size()) i = 0; mAcoustics->setMaterial(mMaterials[i++]); }` You would be responsible for any error conditions or `break` condition needed. (note: you need to index from `0` not `1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the index of the current material as a variable outside the scope of the function, or pass it as a parameter into the function.

```
auto currentIndex = 0;
auto buttonPress = [this, &currentIndex] {
    if (currentIndex == mMaterials.size()) 
        currentIndex = 0;
    mAcoustics->setMaterial(mMaterials[currentIndex]);
    currentIndex++;
};

InputManager::bindKeyFunction(0x31 /* '1' key */, buttonPress, ETriggerEvent::OnRelease);
```

Comment: Feel free to edit this answer if the code is broken, I typed this on my phone, but the general idea should be correct.